sstableloader failing with org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException
I have been attempting to load database files using sstableloader in Cassandra 4.1, which is failing when loading from an Azure fileshare with the following error
$ sudo sstableloader -d 172.168.11.42,172.168.11.41 /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/                                                  WARN  13:06:33,274 [dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms, tracetype_query_ttl, request_timeout_in_ms, row_cache_size_in_mb, counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms, column_index_size_in_kb, trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb, cas_contention_timeout_in_ms, key_cache_size_in_mb, range_request_timeout_in_ms, dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms, column_index_cache_size_in_kb, write_request_timeout_in_ms, index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes, cross_node_timeout, back_pressure_enabled, permissions_validity_in_ms, max_hint_window_in_ms, enable_user_defined_functions, enable_sasi_indexes, read_request_timeout_in_ms, credentials_validity_in_ms, batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb, index_summary_capacity_in_mb, commitlog_sync_period_in_ms, batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb, windows_timer_interval, enable_scripted_user_defined_functions, commitlog_segment_size_in_mb, sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb, tracetype_repair_ttl, gc_warn_threshold_in_ms, roles_validity_in_ms, enable_materialized_views, prepared_statements_cache_size_mb, back_pressure_strategy, hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb, compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb, truncate_request_timeout_in_ms, slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms, hints_flush_period_in_ms, counter_cache_size_in_mb, max_hints_file_size_in_mb, compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec, batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb] parameters have been deprecated. They have new names and/or value format; For more information, please refer to NEWS.txt
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-22-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-270-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-430-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-450-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-451-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-452-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-55-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-56-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-57-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-63-big-Data.db /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-72-big-Data.db  to [/172.168.11.41:7000, /172.168.11.42:7000]
ERROR 13:06:42,492 [Stream #7caa25a0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.168.11.42:7000
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db.804797b0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp -> /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db: Operation not supported
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:186)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.ComponentContext.create(ComponentContext.java:67)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraOutgoingFile.lambda$write$0(CassandraOutgoingFile.java:160)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.runWithLock(SSTableReader.java:781)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraOutgoingFile.write(CassandraOutgoingFile.java:160)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:39)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.run(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:319)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask$1.call(FutureTask.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.call(FutureTask.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:71)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db.804797b0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp -> /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db: Operation not supported
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:481)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1102)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:182)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
progress: [/172.168.11.41:7000]0:0/84 0  % [/172.168.11.42:7000]0:0/84 0  % total: 0% 0.000KiB/s (avg: 0.000KiB/s)
ERROR 13:06:42,501 [Stream #7caa25a0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.168.11.41:7000
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-270-big-Statistics.db.80488210-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp -> /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-270-big-Statistics.db: Operation not supported
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:186)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.ComponentContext.create(ComponentContext.java:67)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraOutgoingFile.lambda$write$0(CassandraOutgoingFile.java:160)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.runWithLock(SSTableReader.java:781)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraOutgoingFile.write(CassandraOutgoingFile.java:160)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingStreamMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingStreamMessage.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:39)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.run(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:319)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask$1.call(FutureTask.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.call(FutureTask.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:71)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-270-big-Statistics.db.80488210-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp -> /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-270-big-Statistics.db: Operation not supported
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:481)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1102)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:182)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
ERROR 13:06:42,502 Exception in thread Thread[NettyStreaming-Outbound-/172.168.11.42.7000:4,5,NettyStreaming-Outbound-/172.168.11.42.7000]
org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.UncheckedInterruptedException: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.acquirePermit(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:372)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.run(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:308)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask$1.call(FutureTask.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.call(FutureTask.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:71)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1081)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1369)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.tryAcquire(Semaphore.java:592)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel$FileStreamTask.acquirePermit(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:355)
        ... 8 common frames omitted

However, the same data loading works when using disk.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

That's a Java file error, which generally means it's a permissions issue. You'll need to check both sides to make sure you have the proper permissions and check the mount:
Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.168.11.42:7000 org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db.804797b0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp -> /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db: Operation not supported at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:186) at

The two sides are:
/mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db.804797b0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp
/mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db
It's trying to create a hardlink and failing, so more than likely a permissions issue. Verify the user you're logged in as has permissions to r/w from the directory and on the files.

The FSWriteError gets thrown when the Cassandra process does not have the ability to write to the filesystem due to the FileSystemException:
ERROR 13:06:42,492 [Stream #7caa25a0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b] Streaming error occurred \
  on session with peer 172.168.11.42:7000
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: \
  /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db.804797b0-fd84-11ee-8a7a-9be902713f6b.tmp \
  -> /mnt/cassandra/kairosdb/row_keys/me-453-big-Statistics.db: Operation not supported

Cassandra was trying to hard-link the *-Statistics.db file but it failed because the filesystem reported Operation not supported. This indicates that (a) the Cassandra process does not have permissions to write to the directory, or (b) the "Azure fileshare" was mounted as read-only.
You need to check the filesystem and ensure the Cassandra process has permissions to both read from and write to it. Cheers!
